# Was doing a practice test and came across this. What is the value of z?

Tags: pseudocode

```
int z = 5, x = 44; 

switch (x) 
{ 
  case 45: 
    z = z + 15; 
    break; 

  case 46: 
    z = z - 5; 
    break;

  default: 
    z = z * 3; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Switch` statements can be thought of some special kind of `If` statements. With one tiny thing. If case bodies do not include a `break` statement, then case checking continues.

As for the `default case`, it is hit when no other case checks are true.

Those being said, your switch statement can be written as:

```
if(x == 45)
{
  z = z + 15;
} else if(x == 46)
{
  z = z - 5;
} else 
{
  z = z * 3;
}
```

It is obvious what the z value will be when given x and z values 44 and 5.

And, case bodies without break statements are ifs without elses:

```
if(x == 45)
{
  z = z + 15;
}

if(x == 46)
{
  z = z - 5;
}

z = z * 3;
```

So when you run a switch without breaks, all cases are hit.

For further examination, consider this code:

```
if(x == 44)
{
  z = z / 5;
  x = x + 1;
} else if(x == 45)
{
  z = z + 15;
  x = x + 1;
} else if(x == 46)
{
  z = z - 5;
  x = x + 1;
} else 
{
  z = z * 3;
}
```

and this code

```
if(x == 44)
{
  z = z / 5;
  x = x + 1;
} 

if(x == 45)
{
  z = z + 15;
  x = x + 1;
}

if(x == 46)
{
  z = z - 5;
  x = x + 1;
}

z = z * 3;
```

with same given values of x = 44 and z = 5. As you can see I actually added the `x = x + 1;` statement to same `switch on x` with same `case`s and and a new case, in all where after z assignment, with and without `break`s. In first example, the z value yields to 1 even x value is incremented to be equal to 45; but checks stopped because it never got to the else block. But in the second example all blocks are hit and z value yields to be equal to 33.